# Scrolling through a database on click - java Derby

Tags: java, database, derby

I'm trying to make a Java Derby database which must show the next record on click of a button. The tutorial I'm following is: 
homeandlearn.co.uk/java/database_scrolling_buttons.html 
In the method of the button I have the following code:

```java
    String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Employees";
    String uName = "bjorn";
    String uPass= "";
    con = DriverManager.getConnection( host, uName, uPass );
    PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM  App.Workers",ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

    ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
    rs.next();
if(rs.next()){

  int id_col = rs.getInt("ID");
    String id = Integer.toString(id_col);
    String first_name = rs.getString("First_Name");
    String last_name = rs.getString("Last_Name");
    String job = rs.getString("Job_Title");

    textID.setText(id);
    textFirstName.setText(first_name);
    textLastName.setText(last_name);
    textJobTitle.setText(job);  

}
```

When I run the application and click the button once, it shows the next record. But if I click again, the application crashes. I want to scroll through the whole database when clicking the button multiple times. Do I have to declare the Connection `con` and the ResultSet `rs` again in this method? When I don't do this the code becomes:

```java
if(rs.next()){

  int id_col = rs.getInt("ID");
    String id = Integer.toString(id_col);
    String first_name = rs.getString("First_Name");
    String last_name = rs.getString("Last_Name");
    String job = rs.getString("Job_Title");

    textID.setText(id);
    textFirstName.setText(first_name);
    textLastName.setText(last_name);
    textJobTitle.setText(job);  

}
```

Now I get the error message:

```java
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Employees.Workers.btnNextActionPerformed(Workers.java:255)
    at Employees.Workers.access$200(Workers.java:19)
    at Employees.Workers$3.actionPerformed(Workers.java:145)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:723)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:696)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:693)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
```

Line 255 points to `if(rs.next()){` and the error is shown because `rs` points to a null object. How can I let `rs` point to the previous record in the database, so that rs.next() points to the next one?

Comment: If the application crashes and you need help, you *must* show the full error message and indicate which lines are causing the exception to occur. Otherwise you are asking us to guess and to read minds, something that we are not very good at doing.

Comment: When I omit the lines of code above if(rs.next()){ it shows the following error message: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Employees.Workers.btnNextActionPerformed(Workers.java:255)
 at Employees.Workers.access$200(Workers.java:19)
 at Employees.Workers$3.actionPerformed(Workers.java:145) Line 255 points at the line if(rs.next()){ because rs points at a null object. How can I let rs point to the previous record of the database?

Comment: So you are trying to call a method on a null ResultSet variable. Solution: don't do this -- don't call methods on null variables. The larger problem, why the variable is null, is probably not something we can help with unless you show more code. You need to trace back in your code to see where you're *not* initializing this variable.

Answer (score 0):

You know when you declare and initialize the rs variable here:

```
String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Employees";
String uName = "bjorn";
String uPass= "";
con = DriverManager.getConnection( host, uName, uPass );
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM  App.Workers",ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();  // ****** here 
rs.next();
```

Your rs variable is a *local* variable, and so you are initializing only a local variable, not a class field. It is quite possible that this local variable is shadowing a class field, and that this is why you're running into your problem.

If so, a solution is not to re-declare the rs variable but rather to initialize an rs class field, not a local variable:

```
// ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();  // ****** here 
rs = pstmt.executeQuery();  // ****** Note the difference
```

Comment: How can I let the program know that I want rs to point to the class variable?

Comment: @user1189952: as I said above, by not *re-declaring* the field locally.

Comment: @user1189952 by changing `ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();` to `rs = pstmt.executeQuery();` Note the difference.

Comment: When I use rs = pstmt.executeQuery(); the problem is not solved, because the application crashes instead of showing the third record (when clicking the button twice).

Comment: @user1189952: again you state crashes and again you don't provide code in an edit to your original question or the actual error. You must give us enough information to allow us to be able to help you if we're going to be able to make any headway at all.

Comment: There is no output when it crashes. I have to stop the program using the stop button of Netbeans. The tutorial I'm following is: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/database_scrolling_buttons.html and it says to do it without the code above if(rs.next()){ I do not understand what is going wrong.

Comment: @user1189952: it sounds as if you might have an infinite loop going on then. You will want to do some debugging of your program, and NetBeans has a debugger that can help you, since to solve your error you will need to first isolate it. But that is a different problem from the one in your original question, which I have solved for you.

Comment: I forgot to close the preparedStatement, now that I used pstmt.close(); that problem is solved. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user1189952: glad you've got things working. You're welcome!